# How to select text in BASH terminal using the keyboard without mouse?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, terminal

How to select text in BASH terminal using the keyboard without mouse?

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10

Comment: If it's possible it probably depends on your terminal (xterm, rxvt, something else). So what do you use?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/312213/1172302

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps this works ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312213/how-do-i-copy-text-from-my-xterm-without-a-mouse/312215#312215))

You can use [GNU screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/)'s copy and paste commands.

Quick tutorial:

1. Open screen: screen (or screen myprog my args here)
2. Run your program, producing output you want copied
3. Enter copy mode: ^A [
4. Move your cursor to the start point
5. Hit enter
6. Move your cursor to the end point
7. Hit enter
8. Paste: ^A ]

Screen is much more powerful than that (I use it to tab several virtual terminals without the need for a special terminal emulator, and also so that I don't loose my sessions when X crashes or something). To get out of screen, simply end your shell session, or type ^A ^.